# Setting up Hyperledger Caliper with Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 with kafka based ordering

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

I need help in setting up the hyper ledger caliper which is used as a benchmarking tool for hyperledger fabric network with kafka based ordering.

Please help me in this regard

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [caliper-benchmarks](https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper-benchmarks/tree/master/networks/fabric/fabric-v1.4.0/2org1peergoleveldb_kafka) repo contains a sample Kafka network, including every Fabric and Caliper artifact you need. You can further customize it to suit your needs.

NB. Caliper doesn't care about the OSN consensus. If you configure a Kafka OSN (based on the Fabric docs), then Caliper only needs the endpoint addresses of the orderer nodes.